# A jQuery accordion that cycles automatically and other options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Does anyone have a demo of a jQuery accordion that cycles through content automatically with an option to set the number of loops or cycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow has several questions on this topic. One such question can be found here, [How to Add Auto-Rotation to a jQuery Horizontal Accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777133/how-to-add-auto-rotation-to-a-jquery-horizontal-accordion), and it might be worthwhile reading through.

Here are some other sources that you should look through:

- http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/
- http://www.madeincima.eu/samples/jquery/easyAccordion/

  - for this plugin, all you need to do is:

    ```
    $('#your-accordion-container').easyAccordion({ 
        autoStart: true,
        slideInterval: 1000 // milliseconds
    });
    ```
- http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jQuery-common-accordion?

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use whatever jquery accordion plugin you like most, and build the cycling functionality yourself. It is very simple - check out my `setInterval`-based answers below. You can see there that there are private variables you could use to set the number of times etc.

I twice answered something almost identical:

[Added a timer to Animated Collapsible DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4714601/added-a-timer-to-animated-collapsible-div/)

[emulating tabs being clicked to create a slideshow of tabs in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715886/emulating-tabs-being-clicked-to-create-a-slideshow-of-tabs-in-jquery/)